# How to mutate multiple columns following name pattern?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with multiple columns that follow a name pattern, and I need to calculate new columns that is the product of two other columns. I am looking for a tidyverse option, but I would want to avoid to do a pivot_longer as the dataset has >million rows.

Example dataset

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  jan_mean = runif(10),
  feb_mean = runif(10),
  mar_mean = runif(10),
  jan_sd = runif(10),
  feb_sd = runif(10),
  mar_sd = runif(10),
)
```

I can do it manually like this:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(jan_cv= jan_mean/jan_sd,
         feb_cv= feb_mean/feb_sd,
         mar_cv= mar_mean/mar_sd
         )
```

This is a simple example, but I have similar operations for monthly values.

**EDIT 1**

I need to do this for large datasets and I was worried that `pivot_longer` would be quite consuming, so I did a quick comparison of the three methods.

**Method 1** is the manual way, **Method 2** is the short version suggested by @Tarjae, and **Method 3** is using pivot longer:

```
tic("Method 1: manual option")
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(jan_cv= jan_mean/jan_sd,
         feb_cv= feb_mean/feb_sd,
         mar_cv= mar_mean/mar_sd
  )
toc()

tic("Method 2: Short option")
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_mean'), ~ . /
                  get(str_replace(cur_column(), "mean$", "sd")), .names = "{.col}_cv")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with('cv')), ~ str_remove(., "\\_mean"))
toc()

tic("Method 3: pivot wider option")
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("month", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(cv = mean / sd) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "month", values_from = c(mean, sd, cv), names_glue = "{month}_{.value}") %>% 
  select(-id)
toc()
```

The results are:

```
Method 1: manual option: 0.05 sec elapsed
Method 2: Short option: 0.01 sec elapsed
Method 3: pivot wider option: 0.19 sec elapsed
```

So method 2 is even faster than manually doing each column

Comment: I think your desired output in the last line should be: `mar_cv = mar_mean/mar_sd` instead of `mar_cv= jan_mean/mar_sd`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `across` in this situation with some string manipulation with `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_mean'), ~ . /
                  get(str_replace(cur_column(), "mean$", "sd")), .names = "{.col}_cv")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with('cv')), ~ str_remove(., "\\_mean"))
```

```
   jan_mean feb_mean mar_mean jan_sd feb_sd mar_sd jan_cv feb_cv mar_cv
      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   0.838     0.401   0.131  0.329  0.0292  0.911  2.55  13.7    0.144
 2   0.595     0.173   0.0935 0.313  0.105   0.247  1.90   1.64   0.378
 3   0.0546    0.934   0.983  0.536  0.618   0.292  0.102  1.51   3.36 
 4   0.543     0.802   0.569  0.585  0.901   0.742  0.928  0.891  0.766
 5   0.899     0.761   0.245  0.932  0.506   0.526  0.965  1.50   0.466
 6   0.832     0.875   0.947  0.390  0.613   0.607  2.13   1.43   1.56 
 7   0.268     0.421   0.930  0.869  0.873   0.612  0.308  0.483  1.52 
 8   0.475     0.217   0.330  0.0473 0.826   0.903 10.0    0.262  0.366
 9   0.379     0.425   0.479  0.931  0.381   0.223  0.407  1.12   2.15 
10   0.616     0.922   0.707  0.976  0.241   0.619  0.631  3.82   1.14
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I do struggle to understand the different arguments in this application of `across`. The `ends_with('mean')` is clear, but the operation `get(str_replace(cur_column(), "mean$", "sd")),` is hard to understand from the helper functions.  Any quick explanation?

Comment: Basically we do: 1. We remove `_mean` from the column name(cur_colum()) 
2. replace `_sd` with `str_replace`
3. Get the value
4. Divide 
5. Create new columns with new names using `.names` and adding `_cv`

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to convert your data to long format which makes it easy to do the computations per month and if desired convert back to wide format afterwards. To this end I first added an identifier column to your data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(42)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("month", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(cv = mean / sd) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "month", values_from = c(mean, sd, cv), names_glue = "{month}_{.value}") %>% 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 9
#>    jan_mean feb_mean mar_mean  jan_sd feb_sd mar_sd  jan_cv feb_cv mar_cv
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1    0.915    0.458   0.904  0.738   0.380  0.333    1.24   1.21   2.71 
#>  2    0.937    0.719   0.139  0.811   0.436  0.347    1.16   1.65   0.400
#>  3    0.286    0.935   0.989  0.388   0.0374 0.398    0.737 25.0    2.48 
#>  4    0.830    0.255   0.947  0.685   0.974  0.785    1.21   0.262  1.21 
#>  5    0.642    0.462   0.0824 0.00395 0.432  0.0389 163.     1.07   2.12 
#>  6    0.519    0.940   0.514  0.833   0.958  0.749    0.623  0.982  0.687
#>  7    0.737    0.978   0.390  0.00733 0.888  0.677  100.     1.10   0.576
#>  8    0.135    0.117   0.906  0.208   0.640  0.171    0.648  0.184  5.29 
#>  9    0.657    0.475   0.447  0.907   0.971  0.261    0.725  0.489  1.71 
#> 10    0.705    0.560   0.836  0.612   0.619  0.514    1.15   0.905  1.63
```